# How to change preview format of Camerax in Camerax config?

Tags: android, android-camerax

I am using Camerax in Android for getting frames in preview callback but I am getting the frames in YUV_420_888 format. I want to change the format in Camerax configuration. How can I do it?

Comment: Did you mean ImageAnalysis? Because Preview uses private format. What format are you trying to get?

Comment: I want the format in NV21 format but it can't convert it doesn't support it. Where as in default camera it's working fine but it's deprecated now that's why I want to migrate it to latest.

Comment: I don't think that is possible at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using [this version](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera#camera-camera2_camera-core_camera-lifecyce_version_110_2) or higher

Add setOutputImageFormat API for image analysis config. User can select `ImageAnalysis.OUTPUT_IMAGE_FORMAT_YUV_420_888` or `ImageAnalysis.OUTPUT_IMAGE_FORMAT_RGBA_8888`.
By default, `ImageAnalysis.OUTPUT_IMAGE_FORMAT_YUV_420_888` will be selected.